# Have attributes from one-to-one mapped entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to include some (or all) attributes of one-to-one mapped entity's attributes in owning entity.

I have created an example to consider the problem :

```
@Data // Lombok's to contain all getter and setters
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room {

    @Column
    int length;

    @Column
    int breadth;
}

@Data // Lombok's to contain all getter and setters
@Entity
@Table(name = "dance_room")
public class DanceRoom {

    @Column
    int numberOfPeople;

    @OneToOne
    Room room;
}
```

Now I want `DanceRoom` entity to have `length` attribute also in this entity, but they should not be in `dance_room` database table.

Direct solution that I think for it is :

```
@Data // Lombok's to contain all getter and setters
@Entity
@Table(name = "dance_room")
public class DanceRoom {

    @Column
    int numberOfPeople;

    @OneToOne
    Room room;

    public int getLength() {
        return room.length;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to create those attribute in `DanceRoom` JPA entity and persist columns in `room` database table?

Or is there any other way to create such mapping?

Answer (score 1):

From entity names and way of accessing data I would suggest to use **[Inheritance](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp)**.

One would argue that relation databases do not have inheritance. Right, but JPA and ORM tools in general allow us to map these relations to databases.

[JPA inheritence strategies](https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/).

Just make *Room* entity a **parent** of *DanceRoom* entity, following former link.